# Is the PROLOG knowledge base created suitable for the following statements exercise?

Tags: prolog

The exercise was as follows:

**Represent the following in Prolog:**

1. Butch is a killer.
2. Mia and Marsellus are married.
3. Zed is dead.
4. Marsellus kills everyone who gives Mia a footmassage.
5. Mia loves everyone who is a good dancer.
6. Jules eats anything that is nutritious or tasty.

The knowledge base code I wrote was:

```
killer(Butch).
married(Mia,Marsellus).
dead(Zed).
kills(Marsellus, Y):- getsfootmassagefrom(Mia, Y).
loves(Mia, X):- goodDancer(X).
eats(Jules, X):- nutritious(X); tasty(X).
```

Is this correct or have any made any errors whilst writing the rules?

Thanks

Comment: No, every single one of these answers is incorrect. Please read a chapter of your Prolog textbook where they discuss differences between the way *atoms* and *variables* are represented in Prolog syntax.

Comment: Not to mention that you haven't defined `getsfootmassafefrom/2`, `goodDancer/1`, `nutritious/1` or `tasty/1`.

Comment: This is really a weird exercise. We should use a f***ing semantic network for this kinda deal, not Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more like it?

```prolog
killer(butch).
killer(marcellus).

adult(mia).
adult(marcellus).
adult(jules).
loves(marcellus,mia).
loves(mia,marcellus)
loves(zed,butch).
married(X,Y):-
    loves(X,Y),
    adult(X).

'good dancer'(butch).
'good dancer'(zed).
'mia loves'(X):-
    'good dancer'(X).

'mia footmassager'(zed).
'mia footmassager'(jules).
'mia footmassager'(butch). 
'marcellus kills'(X):-
    'mia footmassager'(X). 

nutritious('cod liver oil').
nutritious(hummus).
tasty(hummus).
tasty(chocolate).
'jules eats'(X):- 
    nutritious(X),
    tasty(X).
```

Comment: ...except it looked so much nicer and ordered before I copy pasted it. meh.